# Shaitan influence on Prophets

Tags: prophets, shaitan

As we normal people are always being influenced by Shaitan to do wrong things and we try to avoid all those things to do following the rules, so similarly could Shaitan also have the power to influence Prophets as well in their daily life?

Answer (score 0):

> Summary: Prophet Muhammad SAW was safeguarded by Allah against Shaitan, but no definite answer for other Prophets.

Shaitan could if Shaitan had the ability to influence the prophets, but regarding the Prophet Muhammad (SAW)'s case:

> A'isha the wife of Allah's Apostle (ﷺ), reported that one day Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) came out of her (apartment) during the night and she felt jealous. Then he came and he saw me (in what agitated state of mind) I was. He said: A'isha, what has happened to you? Do you feel jealous? Thereupon she said: How can it be (that a woman like me) should not feel jealous in regard to a husband like you. Thereupon Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: It was your devil who had come to you, and she said: Allah's Messenger, is there along with me a devil? He said: Yes. I said: Is a devil attached to everyone? He said: Yes. I (Aisha) again said: Allah's Messenger, is it with you also? He said: Yes, but my Lord has helped me against him and as such I am absolutely safe from his mischief. (Sahih Muslim)

Source for this hadith: https://sunnah.com/muslim:2815

And in a hadith before it:

> Abdullah b. Mas'ud reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: There is none amongst you with whom is not an attache from amongst the jinn (devil). They (the Companions) said: Allah's Messenger, with you too? Thereupon he said: Yes, but Allah helps me against him and so I am safe from his hand and he does not command me but for good. (Sahih Muslim)

Source for this hadith: https://sunnah.com/muslim:2814a

From these hadiths we come to know that the Prophet Muhammad (SAW) was safeguarded by Allah against Shaitan.

Regarding other Prophets such as Musa (AS):

> And he entered the city at a time of inattention by its people and found therein two men fighting: one from his faction and one from among his enemy. And the one from his faction called for help to him against the one from his enemy, so Moses struck him and [unintentionally] killed him. [Moses] said, "This is from the work of Satan. Indeed, he is a manifest, misleading enemy."
> (Surah Qasas - 15, Saheeh International)

Source for this Verse is: https://quran.com/28/15?translations=20,19,85,84,17,101,21,22,18,95

From the above verse we understand that Musa (AS) was mislead by the Shaitan into killing a man, however this was before Musa (AS) received prophethood.

**And please remember that my answer could possibly contain mistakes and as such is not infallible.**

***May Allah grant us beneficial knowledge.*** **Ameen**